# Float ignored in column div

Tags: html, css

I have the following project [here](http://bit.ly/1pFPQlY) and have configured the columns to use float in my CSS in the hope to have the image column on the left and the content beside it.  In Chrome the content stays below the images.

**CSS:**

```
#WADADetails .propInfoCont .col1 
{ 
width:400px !important; 
float:left !important; 
}

#WADADetails .propInfoCont .col1 #loadarea img 
{ 
width:420px !important; 
height:315px !important;
float:left !important; 
}

#WADADetails .propInfoCont .col2 
{ 
width:230px; margin:0; 
float:left !important; 
}
```

Comment: Please include the related mark-up.

Comment: If you need to use that many `!important`'s, you're doing something wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the width of both columns to be 100% of the available space:

`#WADADetails div{ width:100% !important }`

Getting rid of this will allow the two columns to be side by side.

Comment: I came to say it, but Derongan is right, just be sure to add some min-width and you'll be fine